# PHP - shouldn't 'if (!$_POST)' be enough (without having to specify the field name) to detect if data is being passed through a form with 1 field?

Tags: php, forms

so I've got the latest version of Xampp installed and in the htdocs directory I have an htm page containing a very simple form with just a single text field and a submit button which, when clicked, links to a php page that prints a message saying "*What you typed is:*" followed by what was typed. If nothing was actually typed in the field, after clicking on the submit button, the php page will display an error message saying "*Error: you didn't type anything*".

Here is the code for the htm page:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<center>

<form action="p1.php" method="post">
  Type something:
  <input type="text" name="nom">
  <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>

</center>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is the initial code for the php page:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<?PHP

if (!$_POST) {echo "Error: you didn't type anything";}
else {echo "What you typed is: " . $_POST["nom"];}

?> 

</body>

</html>
```

So with this php code, if I type anything in the field and click the submit button, the php page will display "*What you typed is:*" followed by what was typed but if I don't actually type anything in the field and click the submit button, the php page will display "*What you typed is:*" followed by nothing instead of displaying "*Error: you didn't type anything*".

However, I discovered that if I changed the "*if (!$_POST)*" to "*if (!$_POST["nom"])*", then if I didn't type anything in the field, the php page would display "*Error: you didn't type anything*"...problem solved.

But this surprised me, as I have seen in my course material an example (it is referred as a self-calling form or something along those lines) where "*if (!$_POST)*" is used.Here it is:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Me llamo a mi mismo...</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
<? 
if (!$_POST){ 
?> 
<form action="auto-llamada.php" method="post"> 
Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" size="30"> 
<br> 
Empresa: <input type="text" name="empresa" size="30"> 
<br> 
Telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono" size=14 value="+34 " > 
<br> 
<input type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
</form> 
<? 
}else{ 
echo "<br>Su nombre: " . $_POST["nombre"]; 
echo "<br>Su empresa: " . $_POST["empresa"]; 
echo "<br>Su Teléfono: " . $_POST["telefono"]; 
} 
?> 
</body> 
</html>
```

So why isn't "*if (!$_POST)*" not working in my case? (using Mozilla as the browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when posting like this and having empty fields, it still gets saved as value.

var_dumping this

```
<form method="post" action="fgc.php">
<input type="text" name="horse">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

will return:

```
array(1) { ["horse"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: All your inputs will return a string(0), try for yourself by using var_dump($_POST); on your php file.

Comment: Ok, so in my case, the $_POST array will contain a single element (accessed by $_POST["nom"]) because the form has only 1 element for data to be passed to the php page, right? if we leave the field blank and click the submit button then, that's when it gets confusing to me. I mean, the way I understand it, if we ask the array (with "if (!$_POST)") whether it's empty, it'll say no (expression=FALSE) because its only element has an assigned value: an empty string. But if we ask the element of the array directly (with "if (!$_POST["nom"]"), it'll say it has no assigned value (expression=TRUE).

Comment: sorry for changing the comment after your reply, this was meant to be the comment.

Comment: Yes because !$_POST['NOM'] will ask only what is inside NOM which is nothing, but when you ask !$_POST, you ask what is inside the whole POST, which is an empty string, and therefore $_POST is not empty (had to think about this for a moment)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the `$_POST` superglobal is always defined, regardless of whether or not the method was actually `POST`, or if any data was posted.  However, if it isn't a `POST`, or if there is no data, that array will be empty.

If you convert an array to a boolean, the value will be false if there are no elements in the array.

```
<?php
var_dump(isset($_POST)); // Always TRUE
var_dump(!!$_POST); // TRUE if data was posted (even if empty fields), FALSE otherwise
```

The reason your documentation says to use `!$_POST` is that often times the page will be loaded with the `GET` method, in which case, `$_POST` will be an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ // if the form was submitted

  if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){ // basic validation

   // # Don't forget XSS sanitizing !
   $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);

   // Add data to DB or something

  }else{
   echo 'Error: Required field "name"';
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually you dont need to do an `isset()` test and an `empty()` test as the `empty()` statement does an `isset` test before testing if it contains any value. [See manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) **Quote**: No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

Comment: I read something similar before, I tried it and my code broke, that's why I keep both `isset()` and `!empty()`. Otherwise, `!empty()` is enough ?